# Dropdown menu is hidden by the elements that follow

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a dropdown menu that seems to be hidden by the next folder in the DOM.

```
 div class="dropdown-tracks" >


   <div class="btn-group">
      <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#"><i class="icon-filter"></i> Filter </a>
       <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
         <span class="icon-caret-down"></span> </a>                                    

            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
               <li><a href="#">Latest tracks (first 25)</a></li>
               <li><a href="#"> Most liked tracks </a></li>                                  
            </ul>
         </div>
        </div> 

 <div class="container" id="facebook-vids" style="background-color:#fdfcfc"> 
<!--content-->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.dropdown-menu {
position: relative;
z-index: 100;
}
```

when the menu is expanded, the `#facebook-vids` div overlaps the conetents of the dropdown menu. As suggested by other answers on stackoverflow, I've changed the position and z-index, but to no avail.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: not sure what your parent div is, but I'm assuming that #facebook-vids is 2 levels above as parent than the dropdown. so to fix that you might need to set z-index to the same level of parent div of the dropdown to above the facebookvids zindex. hope you understood what i meant.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the `z-index` of `.dropdown-tracks` is higher than that of `.container`. E.g.

```
.dropdown-tracks {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 50;
}
```